# How to relace string using a math operation

Tags: text-processing

I have a gcode file that I need to subtract 101.54 from every value of Z. The format is `[Z]:[0-9]*.[0-9]*`

Either how can I use `sed` to do the operation, or another linux tool?

Like: `Z:101.6` would end up being changed to `Z:0.06`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will there be other data in the file other than one or more lines of `Z:real`?   is that the only thing on a line? is it at the start of a line or in the middle somewhere?   In other words, what else is in the file that needs to be taken into account.  Please edit your question and add a small but representative sample of your actual data (format it as plain text with the `{}` icon in the editor).  Anonymise it as required if there's any sensitive/confidential data, but we do need to see what the data looks like.

Comment: Given how e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code presents a file format with lines like `N09 G00 Z1.1`, this really could do with a sample of the input file.

Comment: Please provide a fuller example of the input data, including data that needs to be modified as well as data that should _not_ be modified. If there are alternative representations, like if the amount or type of whitespace matter or doesn't matter between entries, then this needs to be made clear too.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "Z:101.6" | perl -p -e 's/Z:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/sprintf("Z:%.2f",$1-101.54)/eg'
Z:0.06
```

This uses perl's `/e` regular expression modifier to evaluate the expression on the right-hand-side of the `s///` operator.   It will work with both integer and floats after `Z:`, and will replace **all** matching patterns it finds anywhere in an input line.

Comment: Or `perl -pe 's/Z:\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?/sprintf("%.2f",$&-101.54)/eg'` to avoid having to explicitly capture the number and repeat the `Z:` in the replacement.

Comment: true. it could also be improved to work with negative numbers by inserting `-?` (or even `[-+]?`) before the first `\d`.   Or even `perl -MRegexp::Common -p -e 's/Z:($RE{num}{real})/sprintf("Z:%.2f",$1-101.54)/eg'`

Comment: Btw, that RE would not accept `.12` as a number, while AFAIK most programs do accept it. Of course the RE to accept that along with `23` and `45.` while rejecting the lone dot is somewhat more annoying to do.

Comment: `$RE{num}{real}` from [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/release/Regexp-Common) matches all of those.   It's the point of the module, to be a library of regular expressions for common (and not-so-common) pattern-matching & extraction tasks.  It's especially useful for patterns that are surprisingly/annoyingly difficult to do correctly

Answer (score 2):

This is a task for `awk`:

```bsh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{$2-=101.54;print}'
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}` Set the in- and output field separator to a colon.
- `{$2-=101.54;print}` For each line subtract 101.54 from second field and print
- You could limit the lines with `$1=="Z"{...}` or so if you need, but then you have to make the `print` command global (otherwise you would omit all lines *not* refering to `Z`), as in

  ```
  $1=="Z"{$2-=101.54} 1
  ```

  or

  ```
  $1=="Z"{$2-=101.54} {print}
  ```

---

Example:

```
$ echo 'Z:101.6' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{$2-=101.54;print}'
Z:0.06
```

Comment: @HatLess, yes that would work universally, but would the original suggestion `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $2-=101.54'` also work?